# Añadir salto de linea después de imprimir array en Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Estoy intentando añadir un salto de linea en el momento que recupero los valores del array con el siguiente codigo:

```
  while read -r line; do    
    declare -a array=($(echo $line | awk '{print $NF}' | sed 's/"//g;s/$/,/' | tr -d '\n'))
    printf '%s ' "${array[@]}"
done < <(tcpdump -lni eth0 -vvv -s 0 port bootps | grep --line-buffered -E -i 'client-id|requested-ip|hostname')
```

El resultado es el siguiente, donde el cursor se pone al final de esta misma linea cuando necesito que se ponga en una linea nueva puesto que si se vuelve a ejecutar el comando el array volverá a ejecutarse con nuevos valores

```
6c:56:97:3c:6f:51, 10.0.1.10, WINC,
```

¿Como puedo añadir el salto de linea al final?

Answer (score 0):

Añade `printf '\n'` o `echo` después del comando que imprime el array:

```
while read -r -d "" line; do
    declare -a array=($(sed 's/"//g' <<< "$line" | awk '{print $NF}'))
    printf '%s ' "${array[@]}"
    printf '\n'
done < <(tcpdump -lni eth0 -vvv -s 0 port bootps | grep --line-buffered -E -i 'client-id|requested-ip|hostname')
```

Comment: si lo ejecuto, me aparecen los resultados cada uno en una linea. He actualizado el **while** en el primer post para añadir unas ','

Answer (score 0):

El ‘\n’ significa salto de linea, es decir reemplaza los : por ‘\n’ (salto de linea).

-e Activa la interpretación de caracteres precedidos por el carácter de escape.

\n = salto de línea

Forma correcta, necesita -e para interpretar los caracteres especiales:

```
$ echo -e “Hola\nAdios”

Hola

Adios
```

Forma incorrecta, sin el parámetro -e, ofrecería este resultado:

```
$  echo "Hola\nAdios"

Hola\nAdios
```

Comment: al poner **echo -e "\n"** me aparece un salto de linea para cada elemento seguido de una nueva linea. El valor del array me muestra siempre 3 resultados y los imprime. Se podría detectar el numero de interacciones y al finalizar hacer el salto de linea?

Comment: Sí, se puede, pero no lo veo necesario. Pon el salto de línea después del ciclo while simplemente. Otra opción: agrega un contador dentro del mismo con un if que verifique la cantidad de iteraciones realizadas, cuando sea menor a 4 ponle que imprima un espacio con una coma, en otro caso que imprima un salto de línea :)

Comment: pero el while continuamente se ejecuta. Como controlo el numero de interacciones?